# What video codecs have most amount of content and thus popular at present/in future?

Tags: video, encoding, codec

I want to find out if I can get some data on the percentage wise distribution of video content, for different video codecs currently used for video encoding. I know there are different applications/use-case scenarios which have different encoder used but I want to consider all that and have a overall usage number(%)

My guess is(highest to lowest % of content) -

```
 H.264(AVC)

  DivX

  MPEG2

  VP6

  Where do H.263, MPEG4, VC-1, RV, Theora, etc. fit in here.
```

How may this look like in future?

PS:I would like this to be community wiki to have get wider range of inputs, if someone with privileges can do it for me please.

Comment: The site isn't for crystal-balling

Comment: @The questions wasn't about 'crystal-balling'. It was looking for data and facts. Anyways you guy's seem to have done your job of closing it. ["not applicable to world-wide audience of the internet-- Hmmm , then how come Video is the largest portion of a data flowing over the internet, no need of a crystal ball to know that, i guess.

Answer (score 4):

According to [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2010/05/01/h-264-66-percent-web-video/), H.264 has already won with 66% of encoded Web video . This article also has some insights of other codecs percentage usage.